# re: ggplot2, geom_line - issue with line plot when x data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Can anyone solve this issue?

I'm trying to present a line plot using 'ggplot2 + goem_line', but the plot is not exactly what I want.

In the plot, x data starts from 0 to 1 and then back to 0, and the problem initiates when the x value returns.

If I use the normal 'plot' function, I do not have any issues.

The code of the two are:

```
g1 = ggplot(sdf, aes(ndX,nW1D1))+ geom_line()
g1 + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```
plot(sdf$ndX,sdf$nW1D1, type = "l")
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to use `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()`. The former connects observations in the order they appear in the data, the latter in the order of the x-axis variable.

Comment: Great. It work very well..  Thank you Lin.